# Where is official documentation for tilde (~) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, tilde

I am pretty sure that `~` in Pandas is boolean `not`. I found a couple of StackOverflow questions / answers, but no pointer to official documentation.

### Sanity Check

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 1),
                   (1, 2, 2),
                   (1, 2, 3),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 612),
                   (4, 1, 1),
                   (3, 2, 1),
                   ],
                  columns=['groupid', 'a', 'b'],
                  index=['India', 'France', 'England', 'Germany', 'UK', 'USA',
                         'Indonesia'])

print(df)
filtered = df[~(df['a'] == 2)]
print(filtered)
```

The df is

```
           groupid  a    b
India            1  2    1
France           1  2    2
England          1  2    3
Germany          4  1  612
UK               4  1  612
USA              4  1    1
Indonesia        3  2    1
```

and `filtered` is

```
         groupid  a    b
Germany        4  1  612
UK             4  1  612
USA            4  1    1
```

So I'm pretty sure it is boolean not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `~` is the operator equivalent of the [`__invert__`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L1054)  dunder which has been overridden explicitly for the purpose performing *vectorized* logical inversions on `pd.DataFrame`/`pd.Series` objects.

```
s = pd.Series([True, False])

~s

0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

s.__invert__()

0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Note: Dunder methods must not be used directly in code, always prefer the use of the operators.

Also, since you've asked, the section on [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) describes its use.

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and **`~` for `not`**. These
>   must be grouped by using parentheses.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Nice explanation. However I believe this operator is overridden from standard python [__invert__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__invert__) to support vectorised behaviour. Similar to the rest of pandas operators.

Comment: Thanks, that terminology needed fixing.

Answer (score 1):

I found it referenced on [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) page. It's about halfway down, I'd navigate to it with ctrl+F. You're correct though, it's the `not` operator.

Comment: Please include all relevant portions of cited links in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=boolean%20mask#boolean-indexing) they define explicitly:

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and **~ for not**. These
>   must be grouped by using parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to: https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html, it says:

```
Bitwise Inversion   ~ a invert(a)
```

Comment: But does Pandas overwrite `~` with a magic method? I guess that is possible with [`__neg__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__neg__)?